# Creating universal Cocoa framework that can be included in a 32-bit or 64-bit application

Tags: cocoa, architecture, frameworks, build, 64-bit

I want to create a Cocoa framework that can be included in a 32-bit or 64-bit application. Is there a way that I can create a single universal build of my framework that will work in both? Or do I have to compile two different versions of my framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. With the default configuration, a new framework will build universal when you build it as Release, but built as Debug, it is by default your own architecture only (to speed it up).

So either build as Release (recommended) or edit the target settings and change the key (Build Active Architecture Only) for the Debug configuration.